# Multiply and display an existing control C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio

I've created a panel in Visual **C#** design, into my form and now I want to display as many panels as registrations in the database table I have. I have this script, but the result is:

```
        User login_user = new User();
        login_user.SelectThisMember();
        lblHello.Text = "Hello, " + login_user.username + " !";
        Booking user_bookings = new Booking();
        Booking[] user_bookings_list;
        user_bookings_list = user_bookings.MyBookings();
        lblTest.Text = user_bookings_list.Length.ToString();

        Panel[] panelBookingList = new Panel[user_bookings_list.Length];
        for (int i = 0; i < user_bookings_list.Length; i++)
        {
            panelBookingList[i] = panelBooking;
        }

        for (int i=0; i< panelBookingList.Length; i++)
        {

            panelBookingList[i].Location = new Point(193, 128+128);
            this.Controls.Add(panelBookingList[i]);

        }
```

[The image with the result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnbnd.png)

That label with " 3 " represents the number of the rows I have in database. Also, what can I do to know that when I press that Delete button that is for that registration in my table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am not mistaken, you do not update the Location of your panels.

```
panelBookingList[i].Location = new Point(193, 128+128);
```

The location should be dependant on your variable 'i'

The best would be to use a stack panel and just dump your panels in it without having to set their location.
That way if you change the layout of your panel you would not have to edit your code further to take into account the new height of the panel.
Stack panel just put the controls one after the other.

Otherwise you need to either hardcode the height of your panel

```
double myPanelHeight = 100;// hardcoded height of your panel
panelBookingList[i].Location = new Point(193, 128+ (i * myPanelHeight));
```